# Why cucumber will find the "runTest.java" to run tests?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

When I write some cucumber tests, I found from some documents I need to create a "runTest.java" file under "src/test/java/somepackage", with content configuring cucumber, like:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"})
public class runTest {
}
```

I found the class name "runTest" is interesting, since if I rename it to any other name, `mvn test` will not find it any more.

I searched about the name conversion from junit site but doesn't find any related documentation. Just want to know more information about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the convention is:

- `Test*.java` or
- `*Test.java` or
- `*TestCase.java`

It's not a JUnit convention but the Maven surefire plugin that defines it: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Ref: https://scompoprojects.wordpress.com/2016/02/03/junit-test-class-names-are-important-with-maven/